# Canonical pages on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, canonical-link

I want to put some **WordPress pages**

mysite.com/page/?pag=2 or mysite.com/page/?pag=3 (4,5,..)

`rel=canonical` for **mysite.com/page/**.

How can I do? I read something like this https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/crawling-indexing/put-rel-canonical-on-non-html-resources, but I'm not very unsure...

Anybody can help me with the code into my **.htaccess**?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try to add next code in your file functions.php (active WP theme)

```
add_action('wp_head', 'canonical');
function canonical()
{
    // $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : null;
    $paged = $_GET['pag'] ?? null;

    if (!empty($paged)) {
        global $wp;
        $current_url = home_url( $wp->request );
        echo "<link rel=\"canonical\" href=\"{$current_url}\" />";
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I use .htaccess file?